# Как использовать Scaffold-DbContext с секретами в EF.Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Создал проект типа *Class Library (.Net Core)*, подключил библиотеки для работы с EF.Core с моей СУБД (совместимая версия Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.2.6)

В cmd выполнил

```
cd myProjectPath
dotnet user-secrets init
dotnet user-secrets set ConnectionStrings.MyDb "User Id=MyDbUser;Password=MyDbUserPass;Data Source=MyDbHost:99999/instancename;"
```

Обе команды выполнены успешно

Затем пытаюсь выполнить в cmd

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold Name=ConnectionStrings.MyDb ...
```

Или в PMC

```
Scaffold-DbContext Name=ConnectionStrings.MyDb ...
```

> A named connection string was used, but the name 'ConnectionStrings.MyDb' was not found in the application's configuration. Note that named connection strings are only supported when using 'IConfiguration' and a service provider, such as in a typical ASP.NET Core application. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=850912 for more information.

Если просто в PMC

```
Scaffold-DbContext "User Id=MyDbUser;Password=MyDbUserPass;Data Source=MyDbHost:99999/instancename;" ...
```

,то всё работает нормально контекст и модели создаются

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема не в использовании менеджера секретов. Секрет, это просто одно из средств создать *именованную строку подключения* --- `named connections string`.

Для того, чтобы использовать `named connections string` проект должен обладать конфигурацией. О чём и написано в тексте исключения. Чтобы обладать конфигурацией, мало сохранить файлы .json (будь-то *secrets.json* или *appsettings.json* или *ВашеНазваниеКонФигурации.json*), нужно включить их как используемые для конфигурации.

Так как, Class Library не имеет входной точки, то и не имеет возможности включить их в конфигурацию. 
А вот именно с секретом может проблем и нет, но так просто его использовать в Class Library не получится.

Чтобы, использовать Scaffold c `named connections string` (неважно, где она будет храниться в секретах или нет), понадобиться добавить в решение запускаемый проект, который может поддерживать конфигурацию, например, Web Application. Хранить конфигурацию и если надо секреты, то же надо будет в нём. Не забудьте подключить конфигурацию в Startup.cs.

Естественно, при Scaffold-e модели и контекст создадутся тоже в нём. А что если вам хотелось бы, чтобы они создались в Class Library? Оставьте запускаемым проектом проект с конфигурацией. А в интерфейсе PCM выберите, как Default Project --- вашу библиотеку классов. И потом выполните Scaffold. Через `dotnet ef` я не проверял, но думаю должно быть достаточно перейти в каталог библиотеки, и выполнить команду из него.